# using a global glfw window in multiple functions

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I Have a `int main();` function and a `int Game();` function where in the main function I have a window I use in both functions. I have defined the window in the global scope and when I try to run the `Game();` function before GLFW loop in main function the window opens for a second and then closes. I then get

> Error: The GLFW library is not initialised

printed from `error_callback();`

Here's My Code

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <GL/GL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void drawText(const char *text, int length, int x, int y);
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* wndow, int width, int height);
void DrawCube(GLfloat centerPosX, GLfloat centerPosY, GLfloat centerPosZ, GLfloat edgeLength);
void button(GLfloat red, GLfloat green, GLfloat blue, int x, int y, int width, int height);
void error_callback(int error, const char* description);

int Game();

int width = 860, height = 490;
GLFWwindow* window;



int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    //GLTtext* text = gltCreateText();
    //gltSetText(text, "ElectroCraft");

    //GLFWwindow* window;
    int width = 860, height = 490;
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        printf("failed to init glfw");
        return -1;
    }
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "ElectroCraft", NULL, NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    if (!window) {
        printf("failed to start window");
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    Game();
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, 0, 1000);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    string text;

    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);
        glClearColor(53.0f / 255.0f, 81.0f / 255.0f, 92.0f / 255.0f, 0.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex2f(0, height-80);
        glVertex2f(width, height - 80);
        glEnd();
        button(192.0f / 255.0f, 192.0f / 255.0f, 192.0f / 255.0f, width / 2 - 70, height / 2, 260, 50);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwTerminate();
    return 1;
}

void error_callback(int error, const char* description) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", description);
}

int Game() {
    //glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, 0, 1000);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose) {
        glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);
        glClearColor(62.0f / 255.0f, 85.9f / 255.0f, 255.0 / 255.0, 0.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwTerminate();
    return 1;
}
```

This could be because I didn't initiate the GLFW library globally but I couldn't seem to do this as I got an error if a if statement was outside of a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the window opens for a second and then closes

Of course, because `glfwWindowShouldClose` in not a function call in the function `Game`. `glfwWindowShouldClose` is a function pointer, so `!glfwWindowShouldClose` evaluates to `false` and the loop never runs:

<s>`while (!glfwWindowShouldClose) {`</s>

```cpp
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
```

> I then get Error: The GLFW library is not initialised

This is because *GLFW* is terminated by [`glfwTerminate()`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__init.html#gaaae48c0a18607ea4a4ba951d939f0901) in the function `Game`. Delete `glfwTerminate()` from the function `Game`.

But note, once you've closed a window, you've to create a new window. An option would be to hide [`glfwHideWindow`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga49401f82a1ba5f15db5590728314d47c) and show [`glfwShowWindow`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga61be47917b72536a148300f46494fc66) a window.

Comment: Removing glfwTerminate(); stops the errors but when I run it it runs the main loop instead of calling game then running loop in game and waiting for game loop to finish before doing main loop

Comment: @Dextron I've no idea what you mean. Did you read the answer completely? What do you want to achieve? Once the window is closed, it is gone. It can't be used again.

Comment: I have removed glfwTerminate() from the Game function but calling the game function before the loop in the main function doesn't seem to run the loop in the game function. I tonly runs the main loop

Comment: Figured it out problem was I wasnt calling glfwWindowShouldClose() properly